# Execute method from immediate window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

It is possible to execute static method from immediate window in Visual Studio when the app is not running.

Given

```
namespace Handyman
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }

        static string SayHello(string name)
        {
            return string.Format("Hello {0}!", name);
        }
    }
}
```

SayHello static method can be executed from immediate window using

```
?SayHello("Miki Kola")
```

syntax and would return the message to the immediate window.

**I'm wondering if it's possible to execute method on object using the same technique?** You'd have to create the object first, of course.

Given

```
namespace Handyman
{
    public class NiceTooMeetYou 
    {
        public string NiceToMeetYou(string name)
        {
            return string.Format("It is nice to meet you {0}!.", name);
        }
    }
}
```

when command

```
?(new Handyman.NiceToMeetYou().NiceToMeetYou("Miki Kola"))
```

is executed in immediate window

```
The type or namespace name 'NiceToMeetYou' does not exist in the namespace 'Handyman'
```

error message is presented. Am I missing the syntax or the concept? :)

Comment: The type `NiceTooMeetYou` simply does not exist in the namespace `Handyman` as far as the immediate window is concerned. Maybe that's because the class isn't public.

Comment: @CodeCaster You're correct about the first part but the reason is not visibility modifier of the class. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Then show the class including the namespace declaration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have made a simple mistake:

The class name is `NiceTooMeetYou` (double o).

And you are calling with a single o:

```
?(new Handyman.NiceToMeetYou().NiceToMeetYou("Miki Kola")) //Single o
```

Instead, do it like this:

```
?(new Handyman.NiceTooMeetYou().NiceToMeetYou("Miki Kola")) //Double o
```

Or change the class name to `NiceToMeetYou` which is I think what you intended to do

Comment: OMG. Thx. Class name should be NiceGuy and method name should be. NiceToMeetYou. It would make more sense that way.